# Redirect controller in magento 2

Tags: magento2, redirect

I added a new custom tab in customer dashboard. If my custom form is successfully executed i need to redirect to customer main page `customer/account`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 38):

You can directly use below code in Action controller

`$this->_redirect('customer/account/');`

Comment: How does it work from a GET controller?

Answer (score 32):

Use below code:

```
private $resultFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $resultFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
) {
   $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;

   parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    $redirect = $this->resultFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
    $redirect->setUrl('redirect/to/destination');

    return $redirect;
}
```

Hope it will helpful to you and for others.

Comment: you my friend is now my god, I pray to you every night! Thank you! Saved me heaps of time.

Answer (score 22):

```
public function execute()
{
$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
$resultRedirect->setPath('routename/controllerpath/controllername');
return $resultRedirect;
}
```

No need to declare $this->resultRedirectFactory in construct as its auto declared in construct of 
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
to which your custom controller should extend.
Otherwise you'll get error during compilation: resultRedirectFactory is already declared

Answer (score 7):

Try this code :

```
 namespace Company\Module\Controller\Index;
    use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; 

    class Actionname name extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {      
        public function execute()
        {
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);

            // Your code

            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
$this->messageManager->addNotice(__("Login Reuqire For Edit Post. So Please <i class='fa fa-lock'></i> Login Now And Edit Your Post."));
$customerBeforeAuthUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('customer/account/login', array('referer' => $objecturl->getEncodedUrl($this->_url->getUrl(''))));
return $resultRedirect->setPath($customerBeforeAuthUrl);
```

Try this code, i hope you can use it :)

Comment: Using the `$this->_url->getUrl()` was the missing detail for me, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To Redirect to specific URL bellow code works fine for me.
Please check this out

```
public function execute()
{
    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
}
```

Here, $url is full url. e.g. http://yoursite.com/customer/account/create/

Comment: This is very useful thanks, much easier to use in Controllers, and with `$this->_redirect->getRefererUrl()` as URL you can easily redirect to referer on error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in controller for redirect to previous page :

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
    protected $_pageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_sessionManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context      

    ) {
        $this->resultFactory = $context->getResultFactory();

        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {


        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $url = $this->_redirect->getRefererUrl();

        $resultRedirect->setUrl($url);
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

Comment: Assigned `$this->resultFactory` in the constructor but not using it in the execute method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

    public function execute()
    {
         $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
    
         .........
         .........
    
    
        $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/account');
        return $resultRedirect;
    
    }
```